# Find Page which leak memory in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, memory-leaks

I am using redgate memory profiler to find memory leak. but this software show only system classes. I want to find page which is creating problem, please help

Comment: Memory leaks in GC based applications are pretty tricky. Are you really experiencing one? I would suggest posting the class itself and asking a question: "where is the memory leak?"

Comment: memory profiler shows only system class name like system.string, system.byte. but i want to know which class or aspx.cs page ceating problem.

Comment: Now that seems to be a terrible profiler. Are you using it right?

Comment: I am using redgate memory profiler.can u tell me by which profiler i can do like that.

Comment: :-( noOne can help me?

Comment: Questions about specific tools are not SO scope. Most probably it is you who is doing something wrong, either not being able to use the tool properly or using a trial/limited version which has limited capabilities. Find and identify the code you have problem with. Check the code. Post it. And fill the language tag, is it C#, vb?

Answer (score 1):

When profiling an ASP.NET website you'll see a lot of system classes because IIS is doing a lot behind the scenes, but ANTS Memory Profiler certainly *isn't* limited to only showing system classes.

Classes for which you have source code are highlighted in bold in the class list, and you can also use the filtering to show only classes for which you have source. If you don't have source, but still want to highlight classes from a specific namespace (eg in your case anything which isn't in System) you can do that by selecting **Group by namespace**.

[image: The class list showing only classes with source]

ANTS is showing you the objects which are held in memory at the point when a memory snapshot is taken. If the class list shows you that none of your classes exist in memory, it's because they don't at that point in time.

You haven't given any information so it's hard to give much guidance in your specific case, but in general:

- **Do you actually have a memory issue?** Use the performance counters on the ANTS timeline to look at memory usage while you use your application. If it isn't going up, maybe you don't have an issue.
- **Make sure you're taking snapshots at the right time.** This is one of the hardest things to get right. Firstly you need to ensure a site has been properly 'warmed up'. If you look at behaviour of the first page hits on a site, you won't be looking at normal application behaviour because of things like the one-off overhead of setting up connections, caches not being used, etc. Once the site is warmed up, take a baseline snapshot. Next, use the application in a way which you expect might cause an issue, then take another snapshot. ANTS compares memory usage between the two snapshots, and in particular shows you which classes are using more memory between the snapshots. Then repeat your actions (use your site in the same way followed by taking another snapshot), and look for similar increases.
- **Find out why the increase happens.** Once you've identified something which appears to be an issue, use the instance retention graph to understand the chains of references which cause that object to be held in memory.

A common issue with diagnosing ASP.NET memory leaks is when leaking only a very small amount of memory but doing it very often, for example on every page load. A site may appear fine in a dev environment, but then fail under load in production. A useful starting approach can be to use a load generation tool (you can start with something like the free tinyget tool which comes with IIS6, or use more sophisticated load tests if you have them), and profile the performance of the application under those conditions. Profiling in production is a risky measure and should only ever be done as an absolute last resort.